# Advanced jQuery-Fu: Ajax feedback on a single call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a generic function that provides feedback to a user on the status of their ajax call. It will draw some loading arrows after a target, and then replace it with a tick that will fade out when the call completes. Here's what I've got so far:

The function:

```
function ajaxFeedback(target){
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(){
            jQuery(target).after("<img src='/images/loading/small_dark_arrows.gif' class='loading_arrows'>");
            jQuery.ajaxSetup({beforeSend: ''});
        },
        complete: function(){
            jQuery(target).siblings(".loading_arrows").replaceWith("<img src='/images/icons/tick.png' class='loading_arrows'>");
            jQuery(target).siblings(".loading_arrows").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                jQuery(target).siblings(".loading_arrows").remove();
            });
            jQuery.ajaxSetup({complete: ''});
        }
    });
}
```

In use:

```
function saveDefaultBlockGroup(e){
    // e is the event from a button click 
    ajaxFeedback(e.target);
    jQuery.get("ajax/derp.cfm");
    return false;
}
```

This works great, but there's a few problems. If we later decide to define other things in jQuery.ajaxSetup this function will nuke them. Also if something happens in between  ajaxFeedback(e.target) and the ajax call we will get unexpected results (unlikely, but I like my code to be a bit more bullet proof).

Suggestions? I want to keep the usage syntax simple, but the function can get crazy if we need to.

EDIT: Most of the ajax requests on the page WILL NOT USE THIS. Only a few specific places throughout the site. This will still come out to sever hundred places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing (adapted from the jQuery source code):

```
jQuery.fancyAjax = function( target, url, data, callback, type ) {
    // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
    if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
        type = type || callback;
        callback = data;
        data = undefined;
    }
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: callback,
        dataType: type,
        beforeSend: function(){
            jQuery(target).after("<img src='/images/loading/small_dark_arrows.gif' class='loading_arrows'>");
        },
        complete: function(){
            jQuery(target).siblings(".loading_arrows").replaceWith("<img src='/images/icons/tick.png' class='loading_arrows'>");
            jQuery(target).siblings(".loading_arrows").fadeOut(2000, function() {
                jQuery(target).siblings(".loading_arrows").remove();
            });
        }
    });
};
```

In use:

```
function saveDefaultBlockGroup(e){
    // e is the event from a button click 
    jQuery.fancyAjax(e.target, "ajax/derp.cfm");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating the `beforeSend` and `complete` callback function each time you submit an AJAX request, why use the intermediary `ajaxFeedback` function? It seems like you could just mush your two functions together like this:

```
function saveDefaultBlockGroup(e){
    // e is the event from a button click 
    jQuery.ajax({
        url        : 'ajax/derp.cfm',
        type       : 'get',
        beforeSend : function(){
            jQuery(e.target).after("<img src='/images/loading/small_dark_arrows.gif' class='loading_arrows'>");
        },
        complete   : function(){
            jQuery(e.target).siblings(".loading_arrows").replaceWith("<img src='/images/icons/tick.png' class='loading_arrows'>").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                jQuery(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

### Update

Try this out:

```
function setGlobalAJAX(target) {
    return {
        beforeSend: function(){
            jQuery(target).after("<img src='/images/loading/small_dark_arrows.gif' class='loading_arrows'>");
        },
        complete: function(){
            jQuery(target).siblings(".loading_arrows").replaceWith("<img src='/images/icons/tick.png' class='loading_arrows'>").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                jQuery(this).remove();
            });
        }
    };
}

function saveDefaultBlockGroup(e){
    // e is the event from a button click 
    var opts  = setGlobalAJAX(e.target);
    opts.url  = "ajax/derp.cfm";
    opts.type = "get";
    jQuery.ajax(opts);
    return false;
}
```

This uses a function to set properties of an object that can be passed to `jQuery.ajax()`. The `setGlobalAJAX` function sets-up the `beforeSend` and `complete` callbacks for the specific AJAX call. You can then add other properties to this object, like the `url` and the type of request (`get`/`post`).

I think this is more of what you are looking for. You don't really need to use global functions as you are not doing something repeatedly on a global scale (each `beforeSend` and `complete` is different).

Comment: Sorry, I must not have been clear. This is for an extremely large, complex webapp. I'm trying to create a generic tool for us to use, so that when we need a specific type of feedback from a user interaction, we can just trigger this function, instead of specifying it each time. The majority of ajax request will not be using this, but this will still probably be used a few hundred times.

Comment: I'm with @Jasper on this. ajaxSetup should only be called once even if it is used everywhere. You are setting it on every request by calling ajaxFeedback(e.target); If you the target is changing just assign it to a global variable before you make the ajax request and read it in the ajaxSetup handlers.

Comment: @LukeTheObscure Try my **update**. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: That seems a lot better way of doing things. I'm curious though... Can you think of any ways to simplify the syntax? The simpler the syntax the more likely it will stick with the other devs and the more likely it will be used. I considered using $.fn.extend, but I think that would confuse people. Maybe a chainable method? jQuery.ajaxFeedback(e.target).get(...). My hopes are low, but I thought I might ask.